# Lists mapping and scanning in Batch

Tags: list, batch-file, for-loop, element

I know Batch is a poor scripting language and you can't expect much from it but I think this could be done, yet I don't know if there are some easier ways.
I want to loop through two list of elements (the same number), connected between them similarly to an associative array. What I want is to keep reference of the position of the item in the first list and get the item from the second list. Maybe this code will explain better:

```
SET Projects=(Project1 Project2 Project3)
SET Files=(Project1.txt Project2.txt Project3.txt)

for %%i in %Projects% do (
    :: Get the corresponding value in Files like SET ProjectFile=Projects[%%i]
)
```

For `Project1` I want to get `Project1.txt`, for `Project2` I want `Project2.txt` and so on. Is there any trick or even a harder way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pseudo arrays here.

First the files are assigned to a pseudo array file[0]..file[2].
Then for each project number the associated file is fetched.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET Projects=Project1 Project2 Project3
SET Files=Project1.txt Project2.txt Project3.txt

set /a file_n=0
for %%f in (%files%) do (
    set /a file_n+=1
    set "files[!file_n!]=%%f"
)

set proj=0
for %%p in (%Projects%) do (
    set /a proj+=1
    call set file=%%files[!proj!]%%
    echo !file!
)
```

Comment: Now I only have to find out how to get a specific value (like the file corresponding to Project2)

Comment: It's a question of your rules. I suppose your rule is for each project one file and the order in both lists is the same. But perhaps it's better to define for each project an own file list, like `set file_project1=file1.c file2.c ...`

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that's way better